# Applying attr_accessible to all fields for a given role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-accessible

I am looking for a way to easily apply attr_accessible to all fields in a model for a given role, so that I can mass assign all fields in my admin console. I'd like to do something like this:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
         attr_accessible :name
         attr_accessible :all, :as => :admin
    end
```

Using :all obviously doesn't work. Is there an easy way I can apply attr_accessible to all fields without having to list them all out, as I have a lot of them, and I don't want to have to remember to do this every time I add a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implore you to actually take the time to add each field as this offers an opportunity for you to think about whether it actually needs to be attr_accessible. That said, this can be accomplished:

```
columns.each do |column|
  attr_accessible column.name.to_sym, :as => :admin
end
```

Comment: Probably want `attr_accessible column.name.to_sym, :as => :admin`

Comment: This works, thanks Josh. I want to be able to manually edit any field in my admin panel, which is why I just want to add them all. I am very cautious about which fields I add to attr_accessible under the default role.

Just to clarify, doing what I am doing won't cause a security risk, right? There is no way for a non admin user to specify the role they are mass assigning as, correct?

Comment: As far as I know, this is secure.

Answer (score 2):

```
attr_accessible *column_names, :as => :admin
```

Comment: how can i have this line run in every model, without having to copy/paste this line in every model i create?

Comment: Use a concern. See this SO => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering to have column_names instead of column :

```
(column_names - ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).each do |column|
  attr_accessible column.to_sym
end
```