# Extend the ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I make something like this:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.encrypt(*attr_names)
    encrypter = Encrypter.new(attr_names)

    before_save encrypter
    after_save  encrypter
    after_find  encrypter

    define_method(:after_find) { }
  end
end
```

1. Where do I have to save this file?
2. Do it need to have a special name?
3. Do I have to call `require` somewhere?
4. Could I save it in the model folder?
5. Is a class declared in the model folder visible from the other classes in the model folder without calling `require`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. config/initializers/whatever.rb
2. nope
3. nope ... initializers are loaded on application boot
4. nope
5. Yup. Rails autoload will search for it.

The rails-ish way of doing what is you're trying to do is:
create a file in lib/encryptable.rb (or app/models/concerns if you're on rails 4) which defines a module with your methods.
Then in your models you can do `include Encryptable` or (for all models) in an initializer:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  include Encryptable
end
```

read more about rails 4 concerns here: [How to use concerns in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4)