# Rails 4 concerns questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport-concern

I have read a lot of stackoverflows talking about concerns, and I have a main question:

It seems *concerns* in *models* are something like the new **"application_model.rb"** since models share code trough it and is fantastic -> **IS IT CORRECT?**. Well, if I'm more or less correct,
**Why do we have concerns into controller if already we have application_controller?**
If is possible, Can you recommend a link about how to use concerns in controller?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use concerns in Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4)

Comment: please ask google first