# Ruby On Rails - Using concerns in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, separation-of-concerns

**Possible Noob Warning:** *New to RoR*

I am trying to use concerns in RoR. Right now I just have a very simple concern writen

```
#./app/controllers/concerns/foo.rb
module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def somethingfoo
    puts "Ayyyy! Foo"
  end
end
```

When I try and use this concern in my controller I get a undefined method error

```
#./app/controllers/foo_controller.rb
class FooController < ApplicationController

  include Foo

  def show
    Foo.somethingfoo # undefined method 'somethingfoo' for Foo:Module
    render plain: "Ohh no, It doesnt even show me because of the error above me"
  end
end
```

To my knowledge `somethingfoo` should be called but it is not. I have also tried defining `somethingfoo` in a `included do ... end` block in the concern but this does not work either.


Is there something I am missing? Can concerns not be used like this with controllers?

Comment: Why are you trying to call anything on `Foo`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15078070/438992, http://blog.andywaite.com/2012/12/23/exploring-concerns-for-rails-4/, etc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you include modules (extended by `ActiveSupport::Concern` or not), the methods of that module become instance methods of the including class/module.

Your Controller method should hence read

```
def show
  somethingfoo
  render plain: "Yeah, I'm shown!"
end
```