# Where to store 'concerns' in a Ruby on Rails project? (Rails 5.2+)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, model, controller

I am fairly new to RoR. I have spent the afternoon reading about modules (used as concerns). I have yet to find a good article which describes the file path that using `include` or `extend` methods looks up (if `include` and `extend` are methods?).

The most specific example I have found was here: [Ruby On Rails - Using concerns in controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394427/ruby-on-rails-using-concerns-in-controllers). This makes me feel that if I wanted to include the 'Bar' module in my `Foo` model I would create a `concerns/` directory in my `models/` directory, and create a 'Bar' module file in this folder.

```
# in models/concerns/bar.rb
modlue Bar
  # do I need this???
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def speak_bar
    puts "model module bar!"
  end
end

# in models/foo.rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  include Bar
end

# I could then perform:
Foo.new.speak_bar
=> "model module bar!"
```

And if I wanted to include a Bar module in my Foo controller I would do:

```
# in controllers/concerns/bar.rb
modlue Bar
  # Again, do I need this???
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def speak_bar
    return "controller module bar!"
  end
end

# in controllers/foo.rb
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  include Bar

  def make_bar
    @bar = speak_bar
  end
end

# I could then use @bar in my views (anywhere else?) as <%= @bar %> and get it to output 
=> "controller module bar!"
```

Summary of questions:

Is this understanding set out above correct in terms of the file paths?

And do I need to use the `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` line in order to use this path system?

Are `include` and `extend` methods?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the file path that using include or extend` Rails does some magic when starting to autoload a lot of things so you don't have to worry later when you call "Bar". This talk is really helpfull to understand WHY you can just do `include Bar` inside a rails model without much thinking https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0a5zv7uBHw

Usually, you want model related concerns inside /app/models/concerns and controller related concerns inside /app/controllers/concerns, but that's just for organization purposes, rails will autoload them even if you use /app/whatever/concerns, so be carefull about name collisions.

You DO need to extend `ActiveSupport::Concern` if you want to use the syntax sugar that Concerns provide, but at the end they are just modules that can be included. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html check this examples, concerns are just a way to write modules to share behaviour with a more friendly syntax for common rails patterns.

`extend` is a method of Object https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Object.html#method-i-extend
`include` is a method of Module https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Module.html#method-i-include (and Module inherits `extend` from Object)

Answer (score 4):

You should always extend your concerns module with the supplied concerns base from Rails.

Pathing is usually `app/models/concerns/file.rb` for model concerns and `app/controllers/concerns/file.rb` for controllers and so on.

If you specifically have logic that crosses the controller and models separation, consider placing that in `lib`, and adding lib to your autoload path.

`include` and `extend` are methods. Most things (almost all) are objects in ruby. So almost all operations are methods on objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do I update the autoload path?

Comment: I would do that in the application.rb file. But you can do it in your development.rb or production.rb files if you only want this feature in a specific environment.

Answer (score 1):

`concerns` are auto-loaded by rails by default starting from `rails v4+`. You can read the [article](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns) written by DHH to get a fair idea of what concern does and what does it try to solve.

However, it gets pretty complicated in determining which `scope` you are in and what `self` is in the method. Check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIp6N89PH-c&list=PL4XBVtvKZKqcoTXHdOCXdiQmh7ke94Hzm&index=60) by Ryan Bates regarding the problems with `concerns`.

To solve some parts of the problem, I generally nest the concern inside a folder and refer it by giving a `class`. For example

```rb
# app/models/concerns/user/authentication.rb

class User
  module Authentication
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    # stuff
  end
end
```

and include in the `model` like

```rb
# app/models/user.rb

include Authentication
```

In my opinion, the separation of concerns helps in isolating your methods. For example, you can create a `Filterable` `concern` in a similar way, and isolate it from your other `models`.