# Rails: dry up front and admin controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring, dry

I have an application including a big backoffice part. I have a "backoffice" folder for my controllers, my helpers, and my views.

And typically, for many models I have a controller for the front, and another one in the backoffice folder.
Like this:

```
-controllers/
      -products_controller.rb
      -backoffice/
           -products_controller.rb
```

The thing is, in many models, I have to do the same thing in front and in backoffice. Today, I have the same method in both controllers, which do the same thing. (I know...)

So, do you have any advice to dry this up?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common patterns for making your controllers thinner and DRYer are [concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4) and [service objects](http://stevelorek.com/service-objects.html).

Concerns are modules with common functionality which can be included into a controller or a model. They are more encouraged by Rails, the folders for them are created by default in Rails 4.

Service objects are usually used in models, but it is worth to take a look at them. Which choice is better usually comes down to the concrete situation and personal preference.

Comment: Thanks! I now use concerns, and this is exactly what I was looking for