# Controller Inheritance how to implement an abstract controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given I have a class A which is kind of abstract and encapsulates logic which is needed in decendants B and C.

```
class A
end

class B < A
end

class C < A
end
```

Furthermore if have resourceful routing which provides routes for B and C and are therefore handled by the respective controllers.

To dry up things I moved shared code of both conntrollers into an "abstract" controller (never to be instantiated and no routes to its actions):

```
class AController < ApplicationController 
  def new(additional_opts)
    render locals: {base: "stuff"}.merge(additional_opts)
  end 
end

class BController < AController
  def new
    super(foo: 1)
  end
end

class CController < AController
  def new
    super(bar: 1)
  end      
end
```

A controller action usally has no parameters. But since the AController is intended to be abstract this approach may be valid, or is it better to rely on instance variables and simply call super and then pulling the needed information from the variables instead?

Any insights welcome.

Edit 1:

Thankfully Lateralu42 suggested Concerns which gets me thinking about; ok what is my real question here i want to have an anwser for? (Like in hitch hikers guide). So it is also 
about then to use which method of code reuse?

Found a nice blog post [here](http://naildrivin5.com/blog/2012/12/19/re-use-in-oo-inheritance.html).

Comment: Your approach is correct. Just because this is controller it doesn't mean that you can't have methods with parameters and have to rely on instance variables.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think your problem could be solved using the concerns pattern (module shared between controllers or models) : [How to use concerns in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4)

Comment: I'm familiar with concerns as well, but for me they seemed not to fit here, since i want to share functionality only and only if they are an AController.