# Ruby on Rails Global ActiveRecord::Enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I really like Rails 4 new Enum feature, but I want to use my enum

`enum status: [:active, :inactive, :deleted]`

in every model. I cannot find any way how to declare for example in `config/initializes/enums.rb` and include every model

I'm very new in `Ruby on Rails` and need your help to find solution

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) this feature created for `dry`ing up model codes:

```
#app/models/concerns/my_enums.rb
module MyEnums
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    enum status: [:active, :inactive, :deleted]
  end
end

# app/models/my_model.rb
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyEnums
end

# app/models/other_model.rb
class OtherModel
  include MyEnums
end
```

[`Read more`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4)

Comment: Great answer.  I also found [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could to use a module containing this enum then you can include in each module you want to use:

```
# app/models/my_enums.rb
Module MyEnums
  enum status: [:active, :inactive, :deleted]
end

# app/models/my_model.rb
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyEnums
end

# app/models/other_model.rb
class OtherModel
  include MyEnums
end
```

Comment: It wont work because enum is defined in ActiveRecord::Enum. So I get this error : `<module:MyEnums>': undefined method `enum' for MyEnums:Module (NoMethodError)

Comment: `enum` class macro available only in `ActiveRecord`.