# Ruby on Rails: get variable from include do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, enums

Yesterday I asked a [quiostion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937298/ruby-on-rails-global-activerecordenum) about Rails 4 Enum and got answer.

So I have defined global `Status` enum in `#app/models/concerns/my_enums.rb` like this:

```
module MyEnums
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    enum status: [:active, :inactive, :deleted]
  end
end
```

Now im trying to get all defined properties in my `Status` enum from controller, cannot access enum because it initializes when module included and if i include it in my controller I`ll get this error:

```
undefined method `enum' for HomeController:Class
```

How can I get this in my controller(like Product.statuses)?

```
=> {"active"=>0, "inactive"=>1, "deleted"=>2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include this module into your controller. You could however try:

```
module MyEnums
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  Statuses = [:active, :inactive, :deleted]

  included do
    enum status: Statuses
  end

end
```

And then in the controller:

```
MyEnums::Statuses
```