# How and where to declare constant that should contain AR object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing app that help people overview results of their training. In different disciplines different calculations. And I need to store discipline in object related to training.

I have to use this values in code to programmaticaly set fields of another objects, calculate results depend on it, and later to compare with it.

For example I have model Discipline and three records with names

- Speed on 400 m
- Speed on 1 km
- Speed on 4 km

So it's some kind of constants and I'm just wondering what is the best practice to declare and access them?

Or may be is there any way to declare predefined objects?

Comment: @Зелёный, done it. 1. Search and research - done before, 2. title - seems to be ok, 3. question - improved. Something else?

Comment: What you mean then say `constant`? in Rails you can't create constant from class instance(like `ActiveRecord` object). I suggest you read about [ActiveRecord Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) i think your case achieved through simple relation if i right understand your question.

Comment: @Зелёный, read it. I think I should ask question in another way, because answer below gaves me direction. It's like enum, don't know why I decide to make it as AR model. So, may be you know is there any way to define enum in module and use it as AR fields value?

Comment: enum already model field, maybe you mean virtual attributes? Can you show some part of code and attempts this should be helpful.

Comment: @Зелёный, no. Now I have model Discipline and it used in few another Models. So I want to replace model Discipline to enum and define values in one place and use it in all Models that needs discipline as a field?

Comment: okey look [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937298/ruby-on-rails-global-activerecordenum/25937972#25937972)

Comment: @Зелёный, could you please tell if I use enum - what is the best way to store additional info about elements like rules, calc methods, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you have "predefined" objects you should probably look into using an [enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759/enums-in-ruby), though I don't really know why you would want to do that with an AR model.  The whole idea behind an AR model is that it's an interactive object backed by a database that can have its attributes manipulated via CRUD operations.

Comment: Is there any way to define enum somewhere global and use it as an object value? I've used enum for visibility field, but I defined it in model module like enum `visibility: [:public_tr, :unlisted_tr, :private_tr]`

Comment: In your constants.rb file, but I don't believe AR is fully loaded and functional at that point in time.  It seems like you don't actually want an AR model ...

Comment: Yep, I don't know. Reasons for AR - use in relations, storing additional information about discipline like rules calc methods etc. Reasons for enum - simplicity, be on rails way, auto generated methods for check, get, set, compare