# Capitalizing more than one attribute in a Rails before_save method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, rails-activerecord, models

I'd like to capitalize the `first_name` and `last_name` of my model instances using the `before_save` method. Of course I could do this:

```
before_save do 
  self.first_name = first_name.capitalize
  self.last_name = last_name.capitalize
end
```

But I'd much rather alter the two attributes in one fell swoop. Is there a way to select certain columns in my model and apply the desired method to them?

Comment: This is actually modifying the data before it is translated into a SQL query. This is still contained in only one INSERT/UPDATE statement

Comment: not sure if `downcase` capitalizes string character(s). Are you sure about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Surya Sorry about that. Revised the code to reflect the question

Comment: @MrYoshiji Correct. Not so much "query" the database but for lack of a better term, select the desired columns of the model and apply the capitalize method.

Comment: But eventually you'll have to write those column names, right? Why you think that this is not the way you want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
before_save :capitalize_attributes

private
   def capitalize_attributes
     capitalizable = ["first_name","last_name"]
     self.attributes.each do |attr,val|
       #based on comment either of these will work
       #if you want to store nil in the DB then
       self.send("#{attr}=",val.strip.capitalize) if capitalizable.include?(attr) && !val.nil?
       #if you want to store a blank string in the DB then 
        self.send("#{attr}=",val.to_s.strip.capitalize) if capitalizable.include?(attr)
     end
   end
```

Then you can just add the attributes you want capitalized to the `capitalizable` array. I use a similar code to `upcase` all Strings in certain models just to keep data clean an consistent.

Comment: With this I get: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'strip' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @CarlEdwards Okay so you are submitting nil as a value for something that's fine you can fix that see updated post. You could drop `#strip` if you want I like it because I don't want users submitting names like "John         ". `#strip` will remove the leading and trailing whitespace in this case.

Comment: This checks out thanks! Despite going through the Ruby docs I'm still a little unclear of what `send` accomplishes. Would mind explaining what it does in this case?

Comment: @CarlEdwards in simple terms `#send` allows you to call a method on on object without specifically writing out the method so this is actually calling `first_name= val.strip.capitalize` and `last_name= val.strip.capitalize`. This is in essence how every method is called although some use `public_send` depending on the scope it is being called from. For more in depth explanations that will not fit in a comment just google what does send do in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @engineersmnky's answer further for Rails 4+ with [Concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4)):

app/models/concerns/model_hooks.rb

```
module ModelHooks
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :capitalize_attributes
  end

  def capitalize_attributes
     self.attributes.each do |attr,val|
       # if the attribute only has spaces, then this will store nil in the DB
       self.send("#{attr}=",val.strip.capitalize) if self.capitalizable_attrs.include?(attr) && !val.nil?
     end    
  end
end
```

then in your models:

```
class Trail < ApplicationRecord
  include ModelHooks

  def capitalizable_attrs
    ["name"] # return an array of attributes you want to capitalize
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an another version of @engieeringmnky's answer:

```
before_save :capitalize_attributes

private
   def capitalize_attributes
     self.attributes.select{ |a| ["first_name","last_name"].include? a }.each do |attr, val|
       self.send("#{attr}=", val.try(:strip).try(:capitalize))
     end
   end
```