# What's a good way to include code from a .rb file in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an object `Foo`. `Foo` has a controller, and the controller has a standard index that displays all `Foo`s in a table containing each `Foo`'s attributes and allows users to filter and sort `Foo`s by those attributes. This part works just dandy.

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @foos = Foo.filter_data_by_params
        @foos = Foo.sort_some_data_by_params

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { standard_index } # Has link to format xls
            format.xls do
                require_relative '../path/to/spreadsheet_view.rb' # Uh oh.
                create_spreadsheet # method in spreadsheet_view that generates and returns xls file
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But there's another part of this that seems dangerous to me. The index view also provides users the option to view the gathered index data as a spreadsheet. However, because trying to use XLS ERB returns an XML 2004 file rather than a 97-2004 file compatible with our company's workflow, I have to invoke a regular `.rb` file that uses the Spreadsheet gem to generate the 97-2004 compatible spreadsheet rather than a `.erb` file.

```
def create_spreadsheet
    book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
    sheet = book.create_worksheet(:name => 'Sheet1')

    fields = Foo.columns

    sheet.row(0).concat(fields)

    @foos.each_with_index do |foo, index|
        fields.each do |field|
            sheet.row(index + 1).push foo.field
        end
    end

    spreadsheet = StringIO.new
    book.write spreadsheet
    send_data spreadsheet.string, :filename => "foos.xls", :type => "application/vnd.ms-excel"
end
```

Now, I'm not sure if using an external `.rb` file rather than an `.erb` file is necessarily so bad in and of itself, but I do realize that `require_relative` is probably a terrible way to go about doing it.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand, `require_relative` can only be used once per Rails session (as with any Ruby `require`) and would define the "create spreadsheet" method on the scope of the entire application rather than for just the current instance of the `FoosController` I'm working with.

tl;dr: What I need is a way to expose a method to `FoosController#index` that can use the `@foos` variable populated by `index` to generate a spreadsheet, much like a view file would, without screwing everything else up - i.e. it can be edited without having to reload the server and won't pollute the rest of my app.

Comment: What do you mean by "pollute the rest of my app" - does it change anything in existing classes?

Comment: I'm only assuming here... But if I `require` that `.rb` file with a naked method like `create_spreadsheet` above, wouldn't it define `create_spreadsheet` permanently for whatever else might want to call a different `create_spreadsheet` method?

I guess my question might better be asked as, "What happens when I require_relative with a naked method? What's a way to include a method from another file once for a particular instance of a class?"

Comment: Put it inside a `class` or a `module`, and there won't be any problem - this is programming...

Comment: There is no such thing to "include once" - `require` _loads_ the file, like `Java`'s `ClassLoader`. It becomes part of the loaded code. There is no need to create "naked" methods in a program larger than a simple script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is handled with [Concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4) in Rails 4. You can achieve a similar effect in Rails 3 by declaring a module and using that:

```
module SpreadsheetCreator
  def create_spreadsheet
    # ...
  end
end
```

So long as this is named `spreadsheet_creator.rb` and is in a path that the ActiveSupport autoloader can find it, you don't need to do anything special to include it. `app/helpers` or `app/models` should be one of those spots even if it's less than ideal. Rails 4 has a `concerns` location for non-model, non-controller helpers like this.

Then in the other context:

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  include SpreadsheetCreator
end
```

This is pretty sloppy design though, as your creator is really worming in to the controller and making a lot of assumptions about how that controller is structured. For example, there's no clear dependency on `@foos`, it just magically propagates. Sharing instance variables like that between separate implementation files complicates understanding of your code.

What's better is to make a self-contained helper class with no assumptions, instead well-defined inputs and outputs:

```
class SpreadsheetCreator
  def initialize(foos)
    @foos = foos
  end

  def string
    book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
    sheet = book.create_worksheet(name: 'Sheet1')

    fields = Foo.columns

    sheet.row(0).concat(fields)

    @foos.each_with_index do |foo, index|
      fields.each do |field|
        sheet.row(index + 1).push foo.field
      end
    end

    spreadsheet = StringIO.new
    book.write spreadsheet

    spreadsheet.string
  end
end
```

Then your re-written controller has a clear hand-off and preserves full control over what's being output from the controller itself:

```
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { standard_index } # Has link to format xls
   format.xls do
     spreadsheet = SpreadsheetCreator.new(@foos)

     send_data spreadsheet.string, filename: "foos.xls", type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
   end
 end
```

Handing over responsibility to some mystery module is usually a sign you're going against the grain.

Comment: For this particular use case, I ended up moving the code from the separate rb file into my controller as a private method that was passed the `@foos` instance variable. The method has the `send_data` separated from it like your answer suggests. I miss having a file in views where I feel presentation-related code should go, but perhaps this is the next best thing.

Comment: Always think about how you might test this sort of thing: A test is easier to write if it has fewer dependencies and integration points. Sounds like you're on the right track now.