# How to add a concern to a model inside third party gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Followed this post [How to use concerns in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4) to try to get concern to work. But it doesnt load the concern.

Would it be possible to add a concern like this to a model I have no control over or how should I do that? Ex if I want to add the concern to a model from a gem I am using.

I have added concern autoload in application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/concerns)
```

I checked how Spree Commerce does it in the [docs](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html) but that method doesn't work at all for me.

```
# app/models/concerns/schedule.rb
module Schedule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  ...
end

Namespace::Trader.include Schedule
```

Comment: `module/class Namespace::Trader; include Schedule; end` but it's usually not a good idea to modify code you don't own.

Comment: I tried to solve it with the console. Found it that it doesnt load the module by default in development mode. If I called "Schedule" in irb it loaded and applied it.

development.rb has a setting eager_load which is set to false. If that is enabled it works right away. What is the downside of having eager load enabled in dev mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application doesn't own the model `Namespace::Trader`, i.e. if you don't have *namespace/trader.rb* file in your application, then what you can do is to create a file called *app/models/namespace/trader_decorator.rb* with the following code:

```
Namespace::Trader.class_eval do
  include Schedule
end
```

This should include `Schedule` module to `Namespace::Trader` class.