# Rails API Best Practice, JSON responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, model-view-controller

I am working on a Rails API backend with a separate Rails/Angular front-end codebase. The responses from the Rails API must be structured in a certain way to match with the front-end flash messages. A(n) (slightly boiled down) example controller response is

`render json: {status: "Unauthorized", code: "AUTH.UNAUTHORIZED", fallback_msg: "Unauthorized request"}`

so basically all my controllers are full of this, and sometimes when there are 5 possible responses for a method (ex: if a user resets their email the response can be invalid password, invalid email, email is already registered etc). A coworker suggested abstracting these methods out into the model, so the model is response for sending back these messages and then the controller can just have

`def ctrl_method
  user = User.update(password: password) 
  render json: user, status(user)
end`

    (where status is another method that provides the HTTP status code based on the object's status attribute)
    My question is is this best practice? I understand Rails MVC and feel like the responsibility of sending the json message belongs to the controller not the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say you're both right. The controller should have the responsibility of sending the message, **and** the methods should be abstracted out--just not into the model, more like a class that lives in `/lib`.

This should make testing easier as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing any more details, I would think about utilizing concerns to deal with the statuses. This allows business logic to be encapsulated without muddying up your models. So you could have

```
module Concerns
  module Statuses
    def deal_with_show
      # business logic goes here to generate the status
    end
    def deal_with_index
      # business logic goes here to generate the status
    end
    def deal_with_create
      # business logic goes here to generate the status
    end
    def default_status
      # set a default status here
    end
  end
end
```

and then in the controllers

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include Concerns::Statuses

  def index
    render json: deal_with_index
  end
end
```

Of course, that breakdown of statuses in the concern is arbitrary. It can be handled however makes sense: by method, by verb, or by some other distinction.

This is a good bit on [concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4).

Comment: Each controller method has its own response, it isn't just get vs post it's index vs show vs create etc.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't change the idea. Using concerns to organize logic that is replicated across controllers is fit for purpose. I revised the answer to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with ActiveRecord errors I think you use `errors.full_messages` and use the same code and status for such errors (status: 'Forbidden', code: '').

Note that you should customize your messages in locale files [see guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models). But it's useful if you want to translate your app in different languages.

Success messages can be inferred from the controller and the action (see below).

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 ...

 def render_errors(object)
   render json: {status: 'Forbidden', code: 'WRONG_DATA', fallback_msg: object.errors.full_messages.join(", ")} 
 end

 def render_success(message = nil)
   message ||= I18n.t("#{self.controller_name}.message.#{self.action_name}"
   render json: {status: 'OK', code: 'OK', fallback_msg: message}
 end
end

class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if @some.update(params)
      render_success
    else
      render_errors(@some)
    end
  end
end
```