# Where to place own module in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I create a **simple module** in ruby to implement on ActiveRecord model.

```
module Parameterize
  def to_param
    "#{ id } #{ name }".parameterize
  end
end
```

The question it's where to place the file?

- app/models
- config/initializers
- lib
- other

Comment: lib : Extended modules for your application.

Comment: If you put your module in **lib**, it will be accessible everywhere and you may just have to include them inside any Class

Comment: 'lib' is not the standard practice anymore. concerns is generally considered the place to put stuff that will be included in Active Records

Comment: [__The Rails Concern are used to DRYING the code for both models and controllers.__](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns) it is more about repeated code. For me `lib/my_module` good choose.

Comment: So what happens when you discover that you need it in a second model? you move it from lib to concerns? what if I stop using a concern in a second model - do I now need to move it to the lib directory? what if I'm looking or where I find the module that I'm including in model X? I have to look in "either concerns or lib" depending on whether or not it's included in just this model or in this model and other models?" better to just keep "things you include in models" in the one place... whether it's included in one or multiple... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These generally are placed in a new directory off `app` called `concerns` - it's worth googling for more info about how that works.

here's a good ref of places to go look: [How to use concerns in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4)

Comment: If my module it's user by model, the **app/models/concerns** it's the right place?

Comment: Yep, that'd be the standard place.