# Rails 4 - Best way to perform an advanced search

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In a custom advanced search form, what is the best way to perform a query to filter results?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

end
```

In many case we have different types of data, for example:

`name` will be a string, `surname` will be a string, `age` will be an integer

In my specific case, i have a form with some filters that user can or can not fill. How can i do a dynamic query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you controller do this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.search params[:filter]
  end

end
```

Then in `User` model do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(options = {})
    users = User.all
    users = users.where(name: options[:name] ) if options[:name].present?
    users = users.where(first_name: options[:first_name] ) if options[:first_name].present?
    users = users.where(last_name: options[:last_name] ) if options[:last_name].present?
    users = users.where(age: options[:age] ) if options[:age].present?
    users
  end
end
```

Comment: you can use `concerns` for that purpose

Comment: please follow this answer to use `concerns`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
User.where("name = ? or surname = ? or age = ? ", params[:first_name], params[:lastname], params[:age])
```

Comment: OP said, `user can or can not fill`. So can you expect `params[:first_name]` each time user submits a form?

Comment: try to use like that  params[:first_name] || ""