# Undefined class method using Rails Concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I did everything pretty much as described here: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4)

But I keep getting error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `parent_model' for Stream (call 'Stream.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

In model/concerns `faculty_block.rb`

```
module FacultyBlock
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    def find_faculty
      resource = self
      until resource.respond_to?(:faculty)
        resource = resource.parent
      end
   resource.faculty
    end
    def parent
      self.send(self.class.parent)
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def parent_model(model)
      @@parent = model
    end
  end

end

[Program, Stream, Course, Department, Teacher].each do |model|
  model.send(:include, FacultyBlock)
  model.send(:extend, FacultyBlock::ClassMethods) # I added this just to try
end
```

In initializers:

```
require "faculty_block"
```

method call:

```
class Stream < ActiveRecord::Base
 parent_model :program
end
```

Comment: seems that stream is loaded before loading concern, make sure that you have applied the concerns inside the class definition

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Stream` is loaded before loading concern, make sure that you have applied the concerns inside the class definition. When rails loader matches class name for `Stream` constant, it autoloads it before the finishing evaliation of the `faculty_block`, so replace constants in it with symbols:

```
[:Program, :Stream, :Course, :Department, :Teacher].each do |sym|
   model = sym.to_s.constantize
   model.send(:include, FacultyBlock)
   model.send(:extend, FacultyBlock::ClassMethods) # I added this just to try
end
```