# Calling a method of another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have controllers named `Children` and `Father` and `Mother` where I need to call a method of `FatherController` and `MotherController` from `ChildrenController`.

I need to pass a JSON data to the both controller(***not at the same request***) `get_details` method from `set_details` method of `ChildrenController`. I am going to call any of the controllers method based on some conditions.

There is **no route** for `get_details` method in both controllers.
I don't need any helper methods to write.

I need to call more than one Controller's method, not by Inheriting.

## Father controller

```
class FatherController < ApplicationController

  def get_details(data)
    ##
    ## I need to do some operation with the 'data' received from children controller.
  end

end
```

## Mother controller

```
class MotherController < ApplicationController

  def get_details(data)
    ##
    ## I need to do some operation with the 'data' received from children controller.
  end

end
```

## Children controller

```
class ChildrenController < ApplicationController

  data = {
      "id":"2",
      "expiry_date":"25-09-2016"
  }.as_json

  def set_details        
    ## get_details(data) -> FatherController
    ## get_details(data) -> MotherController
  end

end
```

Please help how to do this or suggest me if there is any other way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: The controller layer is likely not where you want this logic to live. You might want to consider pushing this to the model / business logic layer rather than trying to pass data around from controller to controller. For instance, create a plain-old Ruby object that knows how to handle the logic and will return the data that you need. `details = DomainObject.new(data).process` Within that DomainObject you can do whatever you need to pull out the data you want.

Comment: I agree with @CarlosRamirezIII that this probably belongs in a model. But if you really want it in the controller you might try making a `Concern` out of the common method and including it in each controller that needs that method. More info on Concerns can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4

Comment: @Dan I agree with you. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Easy. Make the method `.self`

```
class MotherController < ApplicationController
  def self.get_details(data)
  end
end
```

And then:

```
class ChildrenController < ApplicationController
  def set_details        
    MotherController.get_details(data)
  end
end
```

Comment: dont works with rail 5+ : `uninitialized constant ChildrenController::MotherController ` ...

Answer (score 3):

Either remove this logic from the controller or define it in the `ApplicationController`, of which all your controllers are inheriting from.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you simply write your function or method into the **MODEL**

```
class MotherModel < ApplicationRecord

     def self.mothermodel_method
     end
end


class ChildController < ApplicationController
     def access_mother_method
         @result_from_mother_method = MotherModel.mothermodel_method
     end
end
```

Comment: You can add relationships to allow access to the child model from the mother model directly and do any manipulation you so wish on the child model