# Ruby on Rails: User helper method to read attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm trying to use a helper method to determine the value of an attribute for several records. Here is the basic function I am trying to get working (from the view):

```
      <% if Baseline.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first.crf_status(crf) == 1 %> 
        <td bgcolor="#98FB98" >
      <% else %>
```

My helper function is **crf_status(crf)**, and it looks like this:

application_helper.rb

```
def crf_status(crf)
    case crf
    when Baseline then 'baseline_status'
    when FollowUp3Week then 'follow_up_3_week'
    ...
    end
end
```

So a working example would be if **crf_status(Baseline)** would return:

```
      <% if Baseline.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first.baseline_status == 1 %> 
        <td bgcolor="#98FB98" >
      <% else %>
```

Right now, the error is 'undefined method 'crf_status' for Baseline'. So based on what I've read, perhaps I have to reference ApplicationHelper in each controller? That doesn't sound right. Please let me know what you think.

Thanks.

edit. I forgot to make this more clear: crf_status(crf) is being passed an object from an array [Baseline, FollowUp3Week...].

The actual line starts with it as well -> if *crf*.where(subject_id:...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return a method that is to be called in the context, use the `.send` method.

```
Baseline.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first.send(crf_status(crf))
```

Whatever is returned from your method will be executed.  This is a great metaprogramming example.  You want to test against the class of the instance, so use the `.class` method on your case line.  You'll want to return symbols not strings though, so do this:

```
def crf_status(crf)
    case crf
    when Baseline then :baseline_status
    when FollowUp3Week then :follow_up_3_week
    else :default
    end
end
```

Edit: Changed case for type comparison

Comment: Thank you for your response. I get an error that says 'nil is not a symbol'. Do I need to cast this in some other way?

Comment: Can I see the crf_status() method you rewrote?  The last line is returned, if there's any sort of code after the case/end block it will be returned instead.  You can shortcut this by using `return case crf.class`  It is also possible you don't want to running `.class` on crf.  Are you sending instances and checking classes?

Comment: This type of comparison is not correct. Case statements in ruby use the `===` method for comparison. You can't use that method to compare classes. For example: `String === String # false` and `String === "" # true`. The correct solution is to use: `case crf` (i.e. don't check the class).

Answer (score 2):

When you do method chaining like `.first.crf_status(crf)` you don't get a fresh global scope every time. I.e. to get this example to work your `crf_status` would need to be defined as an instance method on the `Baseline` model.

From a MVC design perspective, it's frowned upon to do database queries (i.e. `where`) from your views; you should do it from the controller instead. The choice to use helpers here is totally optional. By putting it in a helper all you're doing is making it inaccessible from code outside your views.

To cut to the chase, here's what you should write in your `Baseline` model file:

```
def crf_status(crf)
    case crf
    when Baseline then baseline_status
    when FollowUp3Week then follow_up_3_week
    end
end
```

Note that the `baseline_status` and `follow_up_3_week` are actually method calls with the implicit receiver `self`.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, thank you for your help. However, does this mean I have to define crf_status(crf) in each model that I'm trying to retrieve a status from? Thanks again.

Comment: there are ways to share a method between your models without copying and pasting it. Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4) about "concerns" in Rails. More generally /  outside Rails you can use a module or inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling "crf_status" on an instance of a model, helpers can only be called on views and controllers.

You have to do something like this

```
<% if crf.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first.send(crf_status(crf)) == 1 %> 
  <td bgcolor="#98FB98" >
<% else %>
```

Anyway, that looks like a weird code smell (making queries on view is not right and that crf_status looks like something that you should move inside your models)