# Check User Input Before Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Good Day All!

**Edited for better understanding.**

First model is Inventory and in this model I have Product_Type, Product_Name and User_ID.

Second model I have Users which consist of First_Name, Last_Name and Pin_Number.

On my Inventories page I have a form for checking out said Product_Type and Product_Name, also a place for a user to put their Pin_Number in. On submit, it will check the Pin_Number they have typed in and validate it in the Users model and if the Pin_Number is correct it will create an entry with said Product_Type, Product_Name and User_ID (which is pulled from Pin_Number that was submitted.)

I am just trying to figure out how to validate that Pin_Number they submitted.

Thats why I thought I had to do some kind of validation and an if statement based on that validation. Not sure how to go about that.

I hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: Looks like you need a `before_validation` callback.

Comment: Do you have a sessions controller so that you know the `current_user`? Is the user entering the PIN essentially the user entering their password each time they want to create the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am just trying to figure out how to validate that Pin_Number they submitted.

What constitutes a valid `pin_number`? Just that it allows you to successfully look up a `User`? What if a user enters another user's `pin_number`? Is that considered 'valid'? Something to think about...

It would be helpful if you would add to your question what your `params` look like upon form submission. But, we can do some guess work.

So, let's assume that params looks something like:

```
{..., "inventory"=>{"product_type"=>"foo", "product_name"=>"Bar"}, "pin_number"=>5, ...}
```

In your controller, you'll probably do something like:

```
if @user = User.find_by(pin_number: params[:pin_number])
  @inventory = Inventory.new(inventory_params)
  @inventory.user = @user
  if @inventory.valid?
    @inventory.save
    # perhaps do some other stuff...
  else 
    # handle the case where the `@inventory` is not valid
  end
else
  # handle the case where the `@user` was not found
end
```

This assumes you have something like:

```
private 

  def inventory_params
    params.require(:inventory).permit(:product_type, :product_name)
  end
```

In your `Inventory` model, you probably want to do something like (I apologize, I'm not on Rails 5 yet, so some of the syntax may be incorrect):

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base 

  validates :user_id,
            :product_type,
            :product_name,
            presence: true

  belongs_to :user

end
```

You probably also want to consider adding an index on `User.pin_number` if you're going to be doing a lot of finding by it.

Comment: See Edited Question.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, I couldn't figure out how to do it. But this example was what I was thinking. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Also, it was really great that you clarified your question - super helpful!

Comment: So I am getting an error. "No template found for InventoriesController#create, rendering head :no_content" not sure what that is about but also, i added id to@inventory.user = @user.id, that should give me the user id instead of pin number right? The reason I ask is because I want to grab user_id based on the pin number.

Comment: On the `No template` error, you should post a new question. On the second part, you don't need to do `@inventory.user = @user.id` because Rails knows how to use the `id` field already based on your `belongs_to :user` statement.

Comment: Oh ok, Thank again jvillian! I will post new question for that error.

Comment: jvillian, i am having an issue with this. it seems it only presents the input of the pin when i want to use the pin to lookup the user's data and then add the user's id for user_id. i can do this in rails console but not in the app. any suggestions?

Comment: example of output it shows: "inventory"=>{"eq_type_id"=>"1", "equipment_id"=>"1", "chauffeur_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1985"} but i want user_id to be the users id not the pin number.

Comment: Bummer! Unfortunately, I can't debug your code in the comments section (too hard, and that's not what comments are for). If you like, post a new question and mention me in the comments. I'll try to take a look at it. But, I'll need more to go on that what you have above.

Comment: i appreciate the help. I will post a new one and give everything i can about what i currently have and trying.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question right, but sounds like a custom validator to me.

You can learn more about custom validators in the official Rails documentation under "[Custom Validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)"

Also, consider moving the class for the custom validator you'll build to a concern, which is a great way to make it reusable. You can find more information on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4) and [this nice tutorial](https://www.viget.com/articles/slimming-down-your-models-and-controllers).

Comment: Thank you I will check it out.