# Where do I place model extension methods in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Rails 5 application, and have a number of methods that apply across multiple models.

I was thinking about putting them in:

```
lib/model_extension.rb
```

and then, in every model that uses these methods, I would add:

```
include ModelExtension
```

Would you recommend doing it differently, for Rails 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `ActiveSupport::Concern` and place it in `app/models/concerns`.  This is the conventional approach since Rails 4+ http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

You don't have to follow this convention. Refer to this issue for some good discussion: [How to use concerns in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 0):

This is what [concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) are for. They should go in `app/models/concerns`, which `rails new` creates for you.

Comment: as in app/models/concerns/model_extension.rb, or app/models/conerns.rb and if it's the latter, I don't have to explicitly include it in the model where I want it used?

Comment: `app/models/concerns` is a directory that will already exist in your Rails 5.1 app.