# Is there any design pattern for using helper methods in models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any design pattern in Rails by which i can use helper methods in models, without using `include ActionView::Helpers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionView::Helpers are intended to be used in your view code. If you have code that you want to use in you model and view, I would recommend creating a helper method in your model.

If you want to create a method that is used in multiple models, I would use concerns. Concerns are used to extract common chunks of code from models to DRY them up.
Look here for more info

- [How to use concerns in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4)
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

An alternative to concerns is to create a superclass for common models to inherit from where you can add helper methods

Answer (score 0):

You can for example call **one helper at a time** if you want.

`ApplicationController.helpers.my_helper_method`