# Rails basic associations for all models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a ton of models (>50) and each share a **same** set associations.

Like so.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :created_by_user, foreign_key: :created_by, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :updated_by_user, foreign_key: :updated_by, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :deleted_by_user, foreign_key: :deleted_by, class_name: 'User'
    # other associations
end
```

Since the relation is **exactly same** for all my models (we need to keep track which user changed a record), anyway to to include these associations with one call?

Something like this? (this doesn't work)

Basically I would like something like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DefaultUserAssociation
  # other associations
end
```

Comment: are you saying that putting them into model concerns doesn't work?

Comment: You might want to checkout this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25858075/2545197

Comment: @Abhinay i never tried that, until now (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move it to a concern

**app/models/concerns/default_user_association.rb**

```
module DefaultUserAssociation
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :created_by_user, foreign_key: :created_by, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :updated_by_user, foreign_key: :updated_by, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :deleted_by_user, foreign_key: :deleted_by, class_name: 'User'
  end
end
```

and include it in the required models

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DefaultUserAssociation
end
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed! New that that concerns folder would come in handy some day ... :-)