# Rails keeping params DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I have a model named "seo"

```
class Seo < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :seoable, polymorphic: true
    # more code
  end
```

Many models in my application has_one seo. For example

```
 class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :seo, as: :seoable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :seo, dependent: :destroy
    # more code
  end
```

My question is, what is the best way to keep params in my controllers dry. For example I have the following code in my posts_controller

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(seo_attributes: [:id, :title, :meta_description, :etc])
end
```

Every model will repeat the above. How do I keep this DRY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an example where you could use a [concern](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html):

```
# in app/models/concern/seoable.rb
require 'active_support/concern'

module Seoable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_one :seo, as: :seoable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :seo, dependent: :destroy
  end
end

# in your models
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  include Seoable
end
```

And for the controllers, you could add a method into `AplicationController` that allows simplified the call:

```
# in the application_controller
def params_with_seo_attributes(namespace)
  params.require(namespace).permit(seo_attributes: [:id, :title, :meta_description, :etc])
end

# and use it in your controllers like this
def post_params
  params_with_seo_attributes(:post)
end
```

Comment: Apparently permit can be used once. I modified your code a bit.

def params_with_seo_attributes
  [seo_attributes: [:id, :title, :meta_description, :etc]]
end

in my post controller

def post_params
  permitted_params = [:foo, :bar] + params_with_seo_attributes
  params.require(:post).permit(permitted_params)
end

Answer (score 0):

You could make one controller that has that `post_params` method, and then the rest of the controllers that need to use it, can inherit from that controller

Answer (score 0):

So if the `has_one :seo, as: :seoable` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :seo, dependent: :destroy` are repeated in multiple models then you can use **Rails Concerns** for it.

If you want to learn how to make concerns see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a base controller like the follows

```
class ResourceController < ApplicationController
        private
        def resource_params
            params.require(resource_name).permit(seo_attributes: [:id, :title, :meta_description, :etc])
        end
end
```

And in post controller you can use them as dry like this

```
class PostController < ResourceController    
            def resource_name
                :post
            end
end
```

And again use in any other controller like Blog as follows

```
class BlogController < ResourceController    
                def resource_name
                    :blog
                end
    end
```